# Conditional expectation of mean given extreme value for uniform on discrete set.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Say we have $X \sim unif\{1,\dots,\theta\}$.
I am interested in understanding how one can compute $E[\bar{X}|X_{(n)}]$. 
Where $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{\theta}X_i$ and $X_{(n)} = max(X_i)$

$$E[\bar{X}|X_{(n)}] = E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i | X_{(n)}]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[X_i|X_{(n)}] = E[X|X_{(n)}]$$

So we are interested in: $E[X|X_{(n)}] = \sum xP(x|X_{(n)})$

I am confused as to how we can find $P(x|X_{(n)})$

Here is a try: $P(x|x \leq X_{(n)}) = \frac{P(x , x \leq X_{(n)})}{P(x \leq X_{(n)})} = \frac{P(x)}{P(x \leq X_{(n)})} = \frac{1/\theta}{X_{n}/\theta} = \frac{1}{X_{(n)}}$

Which will give us finally for the conditional expectation $E[X|X_{(n)}] = \frac{X_{(n)}+1}{2} = E[\bar{X}|X_{(n)}]$

My issue with this is that if we have some statistic $U = 2\bar{X}-1$ which is unbiased, and noticing that $X_{(n)}$ is sufficient and complete. By the Lehmann Scheffe theorem, $E[U|X_{(n)}]$ should be UMVUE in particular it should be unbiased.

however we notice that $E[U|X_(n)] = X_{(n)}$ which it self is biased, given $E[X_{(n)}] = \theta - (\frac{\theta -1}{\theta})^n - \dots -(\frac{1}{\theta})^n$

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Are the $X_i$ drawn with replacement, or are they drawn without replacement?  In the latter case, I suspect $E[\bar{X}|X_{(n)}] = \dfrac{(n+1)X_{(n)}}{2n}$

Comment: @Henry Interesting. Would you mind adding more detail?

Comment: @rannoudanames : I observe that you never answered Henry's question.

Comment: @Michael I was not sure what he meant by replacement.

Comment: *With replacement* allows the possibility of $X_i=X_j$ with $i \not= j$. Meanwhile *without replacement* means the original selection was of $n$ distinct values, and the conditional expectation of the $n-1$ values below $X_{(n)}$ will be $\frac{X_{(n)}-1}{2}$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944781/prove-effiency-of-this-discrete-uniform-distribution-estimator?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ i.i.d. and uniform over $\{1, ..., \theta\}$, for some given integer $\theta$. Define $M = \max[X_1, ..., X_n]$. So you want to compute $E[X_1 | M=m]$ for all $m \in \{1, ..., \theta\}$. You can first use Baye's rule to get $P[X_1=i | M=m]$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., \theta\}$.

For $i > m$ we get $P[X_1=i|M=m]=0$.  For $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$ we get: 
$$ P[X_1=i|M=m] = \frac{P[M=m|X_1=i]P[X_1=i]}{P[M=m]} $$
You know $P[X_1=i]=1/\theta$, you can also compute $P[M=m]$ easily.  The tricky part is to compute $P[M=m|X_1=i]$ differently for $i=m$ and $i<m$. You will find the probability is the same for all $i \in \{1, ..., m-1\}$, and is only different for $i=m$.

Then
$$ E[X_1|M=m] = \sum_{i=1}^m i P[X_1=i|M=m] $$

Comment: I will try to work from your hint, Thank you!

Comment: Once you get expressions for $P[X_1=i|M=m]$, you can check your work by making sure $\sum_{i=1}^m P[X_1=i|M=m]=1$.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing why the probability would be different for i = m
$P[M \leq m | X_1 = i] = P[X_1 = i , X_2 \leq m , \dots , X_n \leq m] = \frac{1}{\theta}(\frac{m}{\theta})^{(n-1)}$
So this gives us $P[M = m | X_1 = i] = (\frac{1}{\theta})^n[m^{(n-1)}-(m-1)^{(n-1)}]$
For $P[M=m]$ i find $(\frac{1}{\theta})^n[m^{(n)}-(m-1)^{(n)}]$

Comment: You are not using the correct definition of conditional probability.  Note that there is a denominator. Note also that $P[M \leq m-1|X_1=m]=0$, but $P[M \leq m-1|X_1=m-1]>0$.  Your computation of $P[M=m]$ looks good.